# Running cron job every month and results from the command need to be in a file

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying cron job for the first time. I am trying to generate file which will contain user installed application in Ubuntu and the same file needs to be uploaded to server.
I am unable to generate the text file with that information. Below is the command which i am trying.

Script file which needs to be run for the cron job **/tmp/aptlist.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u) &> /tmp/$(hostname)-$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%S)
```

cron has following entry done using **crontab -e**

```
:~$ crontab -l
0 0 1 * * /tmp/aptlist.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

syslog has following entry however no file is generated

```
Oct 21 14:09:01 Astrome46 CRON[14592]: (user) CMD (/tmp/aptlist.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
Oct 21 14:10:01 Astrome46 CRON[14600]: (user) CMD (/tmp/aptlist.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

Kindly let me know how to fix the issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`0 0 1 * * bash /tmp/aptlist.sh > /dev/null 2>&1`

If this works then I suspect it is because the file doesn't have executable permissions.

You can find that out by typing in the terminal:

`ls -l /tmp/aptlist.sh`.

If that is really the case then you can also edit the file permissions to allow it to run by typing:

`chmod u+x /tmp/aptlist.sh`

This will enable the file owner to run it, but will not allow that to other users. If you need it to run for a different user do:

`chmod a+x /tmp/aptlist.sh`

Good luck!